# multiprocessing errors: logger cannot be pickled, EOFError: Ran out of input

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to start a proccesss as below, but getting the mentioned errors. on the start command.

```
import pyshark
from multiprocessing import Process
import pandas as pd

def get_data(cap, df):
    for packet1 in cap.sniff_continuously(packet_count=100):
        print("ssdp")
        print(len(packet1))
        df.append(len(packet1))
        
    print(df.size)
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cap1 = pyshark.LiveCapture(interface='1', display_filter='ssdp')
    df_sspd=pd.DataFrame()
    sspd_p = Process(target=get_data, args=(cap1,df_sspd))
    sspd_p.start()
```

1st:

```
  File "C:\Users\BMWE\anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1727, in __reduce__
    raise pickle.PicklingError('logger cannot be pickled')

  PicklingError: logger cannot be pickled
```

and 2nd:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\BMWE\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "C:\Users\BMWE\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 126, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
EOFError: Ran out of input
```

Searching the web, it seems that there are some occurrences, but the solution is not clear for me.

Comment: it seems you run only one process - so you could use `pyshak` and `DataFrame` directly in `get_data` - and then it doesn't have to `pickle` it

Comment: There is about to be another process similar to this one. Any way, I'm not plan to use the pickle, but it is part of the library I'm using. Therefore I'm asking about it

Comment: you don't plan to use `pickle` but `multiprocessing` uses `pickle` to send data to process - `args=(cap1,df_sspd)`. But some objects can't be pickled and this makes problem.

Comment: @furas, so what shall I do?

Comment: as I said before I would use `cap1 = pyshark...` directly in `get_data` and then it doesn't have to send it to process - so it doesn't have to pickle it. Eventually I would try to use `threads` instead of `processes` because `threads` use shared memory and it doesn't have to send it - so it doesn't have to pickle it.

Comment: can i do so with 2 separate pyshark captures? i.e. `cap1 = pyshark.LiveCapture(interface='1', display_filter='ssdp')` and `cap2 = pyshark.LiveCapture(interface='1', display_filter='udp.port==12345')`

Comment: I don't knon. If you can two captures in main process then probably you can do this in separated processes. But I expect you can't use two captures at the same time and you may have to use one capture and `sniff_continuously()` in main process and send `packet1` to two processes using `queue`.

Comment: i tried use two `LiveCapture` in separted processes and it seems they can work together but I can't check if they get all data.

Comment: @furas, Can you please share your code for testing?

Answer (score 1):

`multiprocessing` uses `pickle` to send arguments to processes - but problem is `picke` can send normal data but not running object like `cap`.

I would rather create `cap` directly in functions and eventually send only `display_filter`

I tested it with two function which do the same and it seems they can work at the same time and both get the same data - so there is no problem with sharing data from interface.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import pyshark

def get_data_1():

    cap = pyshark.LiveCapture(interface='1', display_filter='ssdp')

    data = []

    for packet1 in cap.sniff_continuously(packet_count=100):
        print("1 >", len(packet1))
        data.append(len(packet1))
        
    print(len(data))

def get_data_2():

    #cap = pyshark.LiveCapture(interface='1', display_filter='udp.port==12345')    
    cap = pyshark.LiveCapture(interface='1', display_filter='ssdp')

    data = []

    for packet1 in cap.sniff_continuously(packet_count=100):
        print("2 >", len(packet1))
        data.append(len(packet1))
        
    print(len(data))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = Process(target=get_data_1)
    p2 = Process(target=get_data_2)
    
    p1.start() 
    p2.start()     
    
    print('Press Ctrl+C to stop')
```

---

If function will be similar then I would create one function and run with different arguments

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import pyshark

def get_data(my_filter, my_count, prefix="1 >"):

    cap = pyshark.LiveCapture(interface='1', display_filter=my_filter)

    data = []

    for packet1 in cap.sniff_continuously(packet_count=my_count):
        print(prefix, len(packet1))
        data.append(len(packet1))
        
    print(len(data))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = Process(target=get_data, args=('ssdp', 100, '1 >'))
    #p2 = Process(target=get_data, args=('udp.port==12345', 100, '2 >'))
    p2 = Process(target=get_data, args=('ssdp', 100, '2 >'))
    
    p1.start() 
    p2.start()     
    
    print('Press Ctrl+C to stop')
```

---

**EDIT:**

There is also problem with returning data. I use `Queue` for this. Because processes may finish job in different order so I use `process_number` to sort data in correct order.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import pyshark

def get_data(process_number, queue, my_filter, my_count, prefix="1 >"):

    cap = pyshark.LiveCapture(interface='1', display_filter=my_filter)

    data = []

    for packet1 in cap.sniff_continuously(packet_count=my_count):
        print(prefix, len(packet1))
        data.append(len(packet1))
        
    print(len(data))
    
    # return data, 
    # `process_number` used to set all results in correct order
    queue.put([process_number, data])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = Queue()
    
    p1 = Process(target=get_data, args=(0, q, 'ssdp', 5, '1 >'))
    p2 = Process(target=get_data, args=(1, q, 'ssdp', 5, '2 >'))
    
    p1.start() 
    p2.start()     
    
    print('waiting ...')
    
    p1.join()
    p2.join()

    results = [q.get(), q.get()]
    print('--- original order ---')
    print(results) # they can be in different order - [[1, ....], [0, ....]]
    print('--- sorted ---')
    results = sorted(results)
    print(results) # they can be in different order - [[1, ....], [0, ....]]
```

Results

```
--- original order ---
[[1, [375, 366, 418, 430, 446]], [0, [375, 366, 418, 430, 446]]]
--- sorted ---
[[0, [375, 366, 418, 430, 446]], [1, [375, 366, 418, 430, 446]]]
```

Or I would use `Pool` and it should return results in correct order. And code is simpler because I don't have to use `Queue` for manually

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import pyshark

def get_data(my_filter, my_count, prefix="1 >"):
    
    cap = pyshark.LiveCapture(interface='1', display_filter=my_filter)

    data = []

    for packet1 in cap.sniff_continuously(packet_count=my_count):
        print(prefix, len(packet1))
        data.append(len(packet1))
        
    print(len(data))
    
    return data

if __name__ == '__main__':

    pool = Pool(2)
    
    data = [('ssdp', 5, '1 >'), ('ssdp', 5, '2 >')]
    
    results = pool.starmap(get_data, data)
    
    print('waiting ...')
    
    print('results:', results)
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I'll try your proposal

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me is that I was sending a running object, so I just instantiate the object inside the target function. Check the same with (cap1 and df_sspd